# How do I play transferred Nintendo 64 games on my Wii U

Tags: wii-u, nintendo-64

I just recently transferred all my Wii stuff to my Wii U, and when I tried to play a N64 game it, said, "This channel can not be launched on this Wii console." How do I transfer Nintendo 64 games onto my Wii u?

Comment: Not sure enough to answer directly, but I recall seeing a generation comparison, and long story short, not all Wii Us support the older games. Really sucks if this is the case.

Answer (score 2):

[This thread on the Nintendo help forums](http://techforums.nintendo.com/message/127807) suggests that it may be possible if you delete the game and re-download it.  It seems that some users have had success in playing N64 games in Wii mode, so I would give it a shot.  I believe the problem may lie in the fact that the software is designed to only work with a specific Wii (to prevent pirating), and that code did not update correctly when you transferred the data to your Wii U.

Make sure you have a classic controller though, as GC controllers will not work with the Wii U.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, transferred N64 games don't work on the Wii U when it is in Wii Mode. I would recommend buying the games again.